# The minimum value of an SQL data type (programmatically)

Tags: mysql, sql

In a MySQL database, I have a table with a column of type varbinary(255) (`CHARSET` is set to `binary`). The values in the column loo like these:

```
-8999130301
NULL
-7010978
-16139671
-2
```

I interpret the values as signed integers.

Now I want to replace all NULL values with the minimum value for the varbinary(255) data type using the COALESCE() function.

The minimum signed integer that can be stored in a varbinary(255) attribute is "-9999..." (with 254 nines), but I do not want to hard code the value.

How can I compute the minimum value for a data type with SQL to use it in COALESCE()?

Comment: Since a `VARBINARY` is not a number but a binary string it's not clear what "minimum value" means if it isn't "all bits set to zero" (aka `0x0`). I suppose you're interpreting the raw bytes as signed integers—I believe you should mention that explicitly in the question.

Comment: I guess one nice feature of an unsigned integer, is that you know the minimum value.

Comment: Since you can't handle 255 byte integers natively you may need to compose the value with string concatenation. I honestly can't remember what I learnt about signed number representations at university but Wikipedia has [an article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations).